# ¿Cómo añadir elementos a un JDialog en Swing?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, jframe, jdialog

Soy nuevo a Java y estoy intentando añadir elementos, como un botón, un campo de texto, una etiqueta, etc, a un JDialog. Básicamente, tengo un JFrame con una JTable y un botón para abrir el JDialog, en este contenedor quiero poner otros elementos. He visto información en algunas páginas y no parece muy complicado, pero no entiendo porque no funciona.

Clase del JFrameForm

```
public class InterfazSwing extends javax.swing.JFrame {

      //constructor de la clase
      public InterfazSwing() {
            initComponents();
            addRowJTable();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      }

      //código generado por el editor                        

      //botón que crea el JDialog
      private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
              // TODO add your handling code here:
              //UpdtFrame frame = new UpdtFrame();
    
              jDialogOptions();
    
              //frame.setVisible(true);
    
      }                                        

      //creación del JDialog
      public void jDialogOptions()
      {
            JTextField nombre = new JTextField();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JDialog jd1 = new JDialog();
    
            panel.setLayout(null);
            jd1.setLocation(50, 300);
            jd1.setTitle("Actualizar");
            jd1.setSize(400, 300);
    
            panel.add(new JLabel("Nombre"));
            panel.add(nombre);
    
            jd1.add(panel);
            jd1.setVisible(true);
    
      }

//código generado automáticamente en la creación del JFrameForm
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazSwing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazSwing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazSwing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazSwing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               new InterfazSwing().setVisible(true);
           }
        });
     }    

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
        private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
        protected javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

La información que he encontrado sobre cómo añadir elementos a un JDialog indica algo como lo que está en la función `jDialogOptions()`, pero cada vez que el JDialog aparece no hay ningún elemento en él. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude llegar a una solución, con Swing simplemente se debe:

1. En el proyecto darle click derecho, crear un JDialog Form
2. Con la interfaz asistida añadir los elementos deseados
3. En el código del JDialog instanciar la clase del JFrame principal
4. En el constructor auto generado del JDialog configurar el tamaño y la posición
5. Establecer la instancia del JFrame principal como `parent`
   Ej:

   ```
    public class UpdtDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
            InterfazSwing inter = new InterfazSwing(); //instancia del JFrame
                                                      //principal

             public UpdtDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) 
             {                                                //constructor del 
                                                              //JDialog
                super(parent, modal);
                initComponents();
                setLocation(50, 300); //configurar la ubicación
                setSize(400, 300); //configurar el tamaño
                inter = (InterfazSwing) parent; //establecer el JFrame principal 
                                                //como parent
             }
    }
   ```

Desde el JFrame principal se puede llamar el JDialog a través de la acción de un botón, en el ejemplo que puse para explicar mi pregunta el JDialog se llama cuando se pulsa un botón.

```
public class InterfazSwing extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public InterfazSwing() { //constructor del JFrame principal
         initComponents();
         addRowJTable();
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           
           /*instancia la clase del JDialog indicando que la clase actual es
           el parent, es decir el frame principal y que el JDialog está 
           encadenado con dicho frame principal
           */

           UpdtDialog diag = new UpdtDialog(this, true);
           
           diag.setVisible(true);//cuando se haga click en el botón muestra el
                                 //JDialog
    }
    
    //método main...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione tu ejemplo necesitas 3 puntos:

1. Agregar un constructor en el que puedas configurar el JFrame

```
    private JButton trigger;
    public InterfazSwing(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        this.setLocation(new Point(200,200));
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        this.trigger = new JButton("Open");
        this.trigger.addActionListener(this::jButton4ActionPerformed);

        this.add(trigger);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

2. Agregar el método main para que puedas correrlo

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new InterfazSwing();
}
```

3. Modificar la siguiente linea en la función jDialogOptions

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

por

```
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Comment: OK, bueno, la cosa es que el constructor y el main ya están, solo que como es un JFrameForm el código que genera cuando se crea el formulario es extenso y para hacer la pregunta más específica no puse el código del main y el constructor. Estoy usando Swing para hacer la interfaz de manera asistida y no AWT para hacerla de manera manual. Actualicé la pregunta con el constructor y el método main.

Comment: Con la actualización lo que faltan son los métodos initComponents() y addRowJTable() supongo que se te muestra la ventana y lo único que no esta funcionando es agregar elementos al JDialog, si es así el único paso que tendrías que hacer es el 3, acá esta un Link con información sobre los layouts https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Si, esos métodos hacen falta, el método `initComponents()` es un método generado por la propia clase del JFrameForm y el otro método es un método que creé, pero que no tiene relación con la pregunta, como lo mencioné antes, solo puse el código en relación al problema del JDialog. Y con respecto al layout del panel, pues realmente ya lo había intentado y solo se muestra la ventana sin ningún elemento.